# How to access Virtuoso RDF store from Python?

Tags: python, rdf, virtuoso

I would like to access `Virtuoso` RDF store from `Python` much like I do Postgres using `psycopg`. After some googling, I came to the this page but I couldn't get either `SQLAlchemy`

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:virtuoso
```

or `RDFLib`

```
rdflib.plugin.PluginException: No plugin registered for (Virtuoso, <class 'rdflib.store.Store'>)
```

to work. Any idea how to get either one to work so I can query and update RDF data from Python?

Comment: i am facing the same problem!!! exactly the same, and after some reaserch i believe that Virtuosois somehow is unknowing to RDFLib. 
If you  figure it out plz post an answer , i will do the same.

Comment: After some reaserch, I found this [Virtuoso wrapper library for python](https://github.com/juanique/python-virtuoso). I have to try it out first but I believe this will do the work!

Comment: Have you seen these [RDFLib and SQLAlchemy bindings for Virtuoso](https://github.com/maparent/virtuoso-python), last updated in September 2016?

Comment: I am having problems installing python-virtuoso that are encapsulated by [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40850108/python-module-from-github-installed-using-setup-py-cant-see-own-submodules/40850171#40850171), in case you are able to chime in.

Comment: @TallTed, i got exceptions when running `python setup.py install`

Comment: No-one can help resolve exceptions, unless you include the text of same… Maybe in a new question, maybe in an issue on the project, maybe in a message to a project mailing list… Totally guessing, you may need to adjust some PATH or similar settings in your environment.

Comment: i think the problem is that those libraries were written with an older version of Python and I am using 3.5 and they are not forward compatible

Comment: for example, they use `print` without parenths etc

Answer (score 3):

There is the following Python module for Virtuoso:

http://pythonhosted.org/virtuoso/

and also:

http://kidehen.typepad.com/kingsley_idehens_typepad/2011/01/sparql-guide-for-python-developer.html

Comment: the pluginException is seeing when using the first module.