# Python module from GitHub installed using setup.py can't see own submodules

Tags: python, installation, dependencies, python-module

I downloaded `python-somelib-master.zip` from `GitHub` hoping to use the API it provides. I ran

> python setup.py install

And it apparently completed successfully:

> Writing D:\SOFT\Python3\Lib\site-packages\python-somelib-1.0-py3.5.egg-info

which then introduced `D:\SOFT\Python3\Lib\site-packages\somelib`.

However, when I try to import something from there in my script:

```
from somelib import SubModule
```

I get

```
  File "D:\SOFT\Python3\lib\site-packages\somelib\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from base import SubModule
ImportError: No module named 'base'
```

I confirmed that `base.py` is present in `D:\SOFT\Python3\Lib\site-packages\somelib`.

Did I not properly install the module?

Comment: Try using [this technique](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268953/how-to-install-python-package-from-github) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You must install modules dependencies in your machine too. If you are using Ubuntu, you can easily do it with "apt-get". Hope it helps! xD